# Gradle copy replace text and place into the same folder

Tags: android, gradle

```
copy{
            from('res/values'){
                include 'myfile.xml'
            }
            into 'res/values'

            filter{
                String line -> line.replaceAll("<!--<string name=\"test\">test</string>-->", "<string name=\"id\">test</string>")
            }
        }
```

I have the following above which takes an xml file and uncomments/replaces a text when building a specific flavor. This works if I copy the file into a different directory but I want to place the file and place it in the same directory with the replaced text. The code above will just delete the entire content of the file.

Comment: Maybe, you could try first copying it to the temp location, then copy again to the original location?

Comment: lol that would actually work. Should have thought of that but I guess I was thinking of an efficient way of doing this. I'm still open for other options but as of right now, the above suggestion would work.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to Gradle, so I am not sure if this is the best way, but I have some tasks that I use on my Windows machine like this:

```
task update_project << {
    def proj = file("$someProjectFile")
    def text = proj.getText("UTF-8")
    def replacement = "2"
    text = text.replaceAll("  something = 1;", "  something = ${replacement};")
    proj.write(text, "UTF-8")
}
```

It seems to work well as long as it is okay for it to happen every time I build.